# How will data redistribute when a pandas dataframe is coverted into a spark dataframe?

Tags: pandas, pyspark

If I call `sparkSession.createDataFrame()` to convert a pandas dataframe into spark dataframe,how will my data be distributed among executors? Are there protential data skewing issues?